# Access denied for user on database when trying to grant permissions

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I can connect to my database without any issues, I have setup a user with a password with all privileges on `*.*` including the grant option.

When I execute the following:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'myip';
```

I get:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'myip' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Yet when I try the following:

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;
GRANT ALL ON test.* to 'testacc' identified by 'asdfasdf';
```

I get `Access denied for user 'myuser'@'myip' to database 'test'`, the schema `test` however can be successfully created.

The only thing that works is doing this directly as `root` on my sever (as `localhost`).

I have tried removing the account, granting/ungranting privileges and flushing them. Nothing seems to work and I have no clue why.

Running on:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out..

`SELECT USER();` & `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` were not the same.

It appears I tried to login via a different IP than what I was actually authenticated as. For example, I was attempting to login as `ip1283.some-random-url.com` yet I was authenticated as `x.x.x.x` (or the other way round, I cannot remember, everything went so fast :P).

I added the first IP (the weird one) and removed the other, astablished a new database connection and everything worked. Very weird.

If anyone can explain why, that would be great!

Comment: Maybe you have dynamic IP, or use a proxy?

Comment: @MichaelO. my IP has been like this for years, I haven't setup any proxy at home ever and no one else certainly hasn't either. It's so weird.